# Get user location when tap a Button

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, core-location

In my app there's a button to add records to DataBase. Every time user tap that button, he adds a record to the DB. Part of that record should be the location of the user when he tapped the button.

So, in my code, when button is tapped, I invoke a method which track the user position. Trouble is that iPhone can't find immediately user's position so record is saved without coordinates (if I create another record around 10 seconds later everything works correctly).

Is there a way to track user only when he pushes the button and adding coordinates when available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

in ViewDidLoad

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Then

```
-(IBAction)button_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


#pragma mark - Location Manager delegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations firstObject];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
}
```